# Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? Ошибка компиляции maven проекта

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, java

Доброго времени суток. Пишу автотест, компилил его нормально через команду mvn test, но через время в командной строке стала появлятся ошибка "No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?"

В настройка проекта в intellij IDE Community Edition настроено под jdk(прилагаю скриншот), в командной строке на команду mvn -version можете также увидеть результат на скриншоте. Я честно сказать уже не знаю что конкретно у меня не так сделано

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы `JAVA_HOME` смотрел на папку с JDK

Comment: @Alex Chermenin спасибо, проблема решилась